# Unity3D - get component

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gameobject

What is the simplest way to getcomponent in Unity3D `C#`?

My case:

```
GameObject gamemaster. 
//C# script MainGameLogic.cs(attached to gamemaster). 
A boolean backfacedisplayed(in MainGameLogic.cs).
A function BackfaceDisplay()(in MainGameLogic.cs).
```

Another `C#` script `FlipMech.cs`, which I need to check from `MainGameLogic.cs`  `if(backfacedisplayed == TRUE)`, I will call `BackfaceDisplay()`from `MainGameLogic.cs`. How can I do it in C#?

In js is rather straight forward. In `FlipMech.js`:

```
//declare gamemaster
var gamemaster:GameObject;
```

Then wherever I need:

```
if(gamemaster.GetComponent(MainGameLogic).backfacedisplayed==true)
{
    gamemaster.GetComponent(MainGameLogic).BackfaceDisplay();
}
```

But it seems like `C#` is way more complicated that this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

in c#, you will get the component using this,

```
if(gamemaster.GetComponent<MainGameLogic>().backfacedisplayed==true)
    {
        gamemaster.GetComponent<MainGameLogic>().BackfaceDisplay();
    }
```

Comment: I tried your method and get this `error CS0122: 'MainGameLogic.backfacedisplayed' is inaccessible due to its protection level
`.

Comment: your variables should be public to use in GetComponent()
Declare backfacedisplayed as public.

Comment: I think it works. the error goes away but I still yet to test fully.

Answer (score 1):

[Nick's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21328230/4320665) didn't work for me when I countered this same problem. The script involved an `Unity3d` asset store that has its own namespace. When I put the class in the namespace, it started working.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using Devdog.InventorySystem;

namespace Devdog.InventorySystem.Demo
{
  public class changeStat : MonoBehaviour {
    // ... rest of the code including the gameObject.GetComponent<>();
  }
}
```